# Scaled Point in Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d

```
xzak = {-10, 10};
yzak = {-10, 10};
fun := x^2 + y^2;        
wykres = Plot3D[
       fun, {x, xzak[[1]], xzak[[2]]}, {y, yzak[[1]], yzak[[2]]}, 
       ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]]];
    Graphics3D[
     {
      wykres[[1]],
      Point[{{1, 1, 1}}, Scaled[{2, 2, 2}]]
      }
     ]
```

Ok guys I have a problem I'd like to Plot3D function fun and then plot a scaled Point in same Graphic. I'd like to make point bigger and could clearly see it.

Comment: `Point[{{1, 1, 1}, Scaled[{2, 2, 2}]}]` -- note where the `{}` go.... Next, perhaps `BoxRatios` and `PointSize` would be helpful.  Also, I would probably use `Show` to combine the graphics, instead of extracting them from `wkres`.

Answer (score 1):

With some bells and whistles:

```
Manipulate[
 fun := x^2 + y^2;
 Show[
  Plot3D[fun,
   {x, -rng, rng},
   {y, -rng, rng},
   ColorFunction ->
    Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]],
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[opac]],
  Graphics3D[
   {Blue,
    AbsolutePointSize[pt],
    Point[{1, 1, 1}]}]],
 {{rng, 2, "x & y Range"}, 1.5, 10,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Row[{
   Control[
    {{opac, .75, "Opacity"}, Range[.5, 1, .05]}],
   Spacer[25],
   Control[
    {{pt, 5, "Point Size"}, Range[2, 15]}]}]]
```

[image]